# A tempered alternative to "I suggest ..."?

Tags: word-choice

An american colleague told me "I suggest that..." or "I suggest you..." is a heavy tone that I should avoid in most circumstances. I agree with him, but what should we say for instead?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mis-hear him? He probably said that should say that you have a suggestion.

Comment: @tchrist, maybe, I don't remember that so clearly, it's several years ago. So "I have a suggestion ..." is the correct tempered usage?

Comment: my wife often uses sentences like "would you like to do the dishes?" or "could you take out the rubbish?"  As literal questions the answers might be "no" or "yes, I could" but the intention is to suggest that I do those things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible ways of tempering a direct command’s apparent harshness.  Here are a few, very vaguely semi-ordered from most to least direct:

- Go to the store.
- You **WILL/SHALL** go to store.
- You must go to the store.
- You have to go the store.
- You should go to the store.
- I suggest you go to the store.
- You really ought to (outta) go to the store, you know.
- I would (I’d) suggest that you go to the store.
- I might suggest you go to the store, eh.
- Ya know, I’ve gotta little suggestion for ya here, bud; I'm thinking that maybe you could bounce down to the store to fetch us home some grub before we die of starvation here.

There’s room for plenty more there, too.

Answer (score 0):

A great all-purpose alternative to "I suggest..." is "How about...."  For example,

> How about running your draft by me first next time, before submitting?

It feels more positive, less scolding, more collaborative.

Variant:

> How about you run your draft by me first next time, before submitting?